# Pure Basic JQuery Camera Plugin - Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a help in jquery camera plugin. I downloaded the plugin from

http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/

And I placed all the necessary JavaScript files downloaded from the site in the same location :

My php program is (it does not have any php scripts although the extension is .php) in the same folder as "js" This is the html code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jqueryCamera/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'             src='js/jqueryCamera/scripts/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jqueryCamera/scripts/camera.min.js'></script> 

    <script>
        $('#camera_wrap').camera();
    </script>


    <div id="SlideWrapper">
        <div id="camera_wrap">
            <div data-src="images/slider/01.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="images/slider/02.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="images/slider/03.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And when I run the program it does not show the images. I have done exactly how its instructed in the website. I have not added any features and changed any parameters.

I have placed the program in the webserver and it can be viewed at :

http://store.touchmedia.ca/mytest/TestCamera01.php

Please help me to make it work...

thanks,

Isaac

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the following link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/camera-slideshow/AgVzZjjJ75Y

Looks like the newer JQuery version(s) do not support JQuery Camera slider, must be because of certain functions/APIs required for the slider were removed in the newer version as mentioned by Nouphal (Thank You).

I downloaded the fixed version from the above link and you can see that in

http://store.touchmedia.ca/mytest/TestCamera02.php

From this, I doubt how far can we trust the plugins which were developed by somebody whom we don't know, and when newer version(s) of JQuery is/are released then the plugin would stop working, imagine we develop a website for a customer and after a few months it stops working and we don't know how to fix the plugin and will end up throwing questions at all the forums found in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Call function when DOM gets ready.

Write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#camera_wrap').camera();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is due to inconsistency between your plugin and the jQuery source file. In your example you are using the latest jQuery version i.e 1.10.2. You should always keep in mind that with each new version some of the older and inconsistent api's are removed and new ones are added. I think this plugin may be using some of the removed or deprecated methods. This plugin is however compatible till jQuery version 1.8.3. You can find the jQuery change log [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) or [here](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/). i have created a working example of your problem in [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/OwOtAjuk)

Comment: Thank you. I have downloaded the fixed version of camera plugin. By the way, is there any way that I could see your code in JSBIN above ? I know that in jsfiddle we can see the code, haven't heard about JSBIN. THanks.

Comment: yes move mouse on the top right corner and you can see the "Edit in Jsbin" option. click on it and you are ready to go. or simply append "/edit" at the end of url

Answer (score 0):

I updated this plugin. It is now compatible with jquery-1.10.2 and bug free

Latest version as of 01/29/2014 available at: http://www.orangecountyseomarketing.com/projects/slider.html
http://www.orangecountyseomarketing.com/assets/js/slider/camera.js

**BUGS FIXED:**

> 1. Resolved latest jQuery version with .on() instead of .live();
> 2. Can still include iFrame with Video, extended size of video to 100%, video can play with any host not just vimeo or youtube
> 3. Working Pause and Play buttons.

Hope this helps.

-*Yamenator*-

Comment: You bet. I hope that helps.